# Running GKE Cluster behind a FortiGate Firewall VM

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have a simple project in which I should implement and deploy a GKE cluster behind a FortiGate FW, the Architecture of my project is (project is deployed on Google Cloud Platform): An external VPC network with an external load balancer with a static external IP address, and a FortiGate Firewall as the backend, another internal VPC network inside it I deployed my GKE Cluster, I configured the routes and policies and deployed a simple VM and installed nginx on it then port forward to be able to access the web site and it worked successfully, however when I deployed an nginx service on my cluster and used the public IP address of my external load balancer to access from the website from the internet it always fail, any solution?

All the internal VPC resources traffic should pass through the FortiGate Firewall VM for inspection.

I deployed a simple VM with an nginx server running on it, and I was able to view the website and all my traffic passed by the FW, but when it comes to the cluster, I can’t view the website.